# Installing mod_mono on Mac OSX 10.9 "Mavericks"

Tags: apache, mono, osx-mavericks, mod-mono

I'm trying to install mod_mono on mavericks, however, I'm getting an error. I have the most up-to-date mono version with Mavericks support. (v 3.2.3).

When I `./configure --prefix=/usr` in mod_mono version 2.10 I get this error:

`checking Apache version... configure: error: Apache 1.3 is no longer supported. mod_mono now requires at least Apache 2.0`

But when i check my version of apache it says

`Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 24 2013 21:10:43`

EDIT: Upgrading your mono version to the latest (3.2.4) appears to work the best. Ensure you have a clean download of mod_mono-2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing Mavericks, you need to reinstall the XCode Command Line Tools. This will bring back the /usr/include/apache2 directory. You do this by updating your XCode and then run xcode-select --install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I had mono running on my server. When I upgraded to Mavericks and Server 3 mono stopped working. During the upgrade process the "mod_mono.so" file was removed. This is what I did to research and resolve my issue which I believe encompasses yours. Hope it helps.

In the directory that you are running your "./config..." command, there is a "config.log". I looked at the config.log and found an error message stating that it could not find the file "ap_release.h" (I believe this is how the apache version is determined). I must have had this file at one time because I went through this installation process before. I went into my time machine and restored the directory (which was removed when I upgraded to Mavericks or Server 3) "/usr/include/". This folder included a directory called "apache2" which included the "ap_release.h" file and I assume it's dependencies.

All is well I am up and running.

Comment: I tried this and it installed with no errors, however, when I try to run localhost/mono it doesn't send any data. Is Server 3 now necessary when running mono for a localhost?

Comment: I don't think Server 3 is required. If you have Apache 2 running you should be good to go. Does your Apache config include an "include" to your mono config?

Comment: Ensure Apache is up and running as expected and then we can start adding in the mono stuff. Can your local Apache instance serve up some HTML pages?

Comment: I have apache2 running as in when i type "localhost" into the address bar it gives me the "it works!" dialogue. I don't have it routing to any of my html files. But it is up and running.

Comment: Ensure your Apache config has an include to your mono config. I know in my mono config I specified the version 4. Let me know if you need and example of my mono config.

Comment: If you could provide an example, that would be great. I've never set this up on my own before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40523/discussion-between-kevin-kulla-and-chris)