# Compiling mod_mono on OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, apache, mono, mod-mono

How to install mod_mono from source on osx 10.9? I downloaded mod_mono-2.10. Apache is installed under /etc/Apache2 and mono is under /Library/Frameworks/Mono.Frameworks. Mono is version 3.2.3.

I tried following the instructions in the Install file with the source and running the command below.

./configure --prefix=/usr --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs

I have no idea what to use for the prefix (/usr, /etc, something else). The last line of the ./configure output is checking Apache version... configure: error: Apache 1.3 is no longer supported. mod_mono now requires at least Apache 2.0.

make and make install don't do anything I assume because the configure didn't work.

Comment: You can find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730245/installing-mod-mono-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/20817587#20817587